# Argument for argparse always needed, I want to make it optional(without --)

Tags: python, argparse

I've done my research but still couldn't find a way to be able to run a python with a random string as an argument and without any arguments at the same time.**(without --)**

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Argument list")
parser.add_argument('string', type=str, help='String for additional info')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.string :
    print("You passed an argument")
enter code here
```

Runs perfectly with argument - **python main.py blablabla**

Crashes - **python main.py**

```
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: string
```

I could use a key word like **--string=blablabla**, but **I want to avoid key word part(--string=)**

Is it possible to handle optional argument without using keywords?

Comment: So you just want a optional positional argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass [`nargs='*'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) to accept zero or more of a positional argument

```
parser.add_argument('string', type=str, help='String for additional info', nargs='*')
```

Comment: Fixed my problem. Appreciate your help!